# How to get a decrement in a list?

Tags: python, list

here' my code , outputs right if it's incrementing, when decrements stack with empty list

```
def generate_list(start, stop, step):
  new_list=[]
  while start < stop:
    new_list.append(start)
    start += step
    if step < 0:
      start -= step
  return new_list

Output:
> generate_list(0,5,1)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
> generate_list(0,0,1)
[]
> generate_list(5,10,2)
[5, 7, 9]
> generate_list(10,5,-2)
[10, 8, 6]
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Because it does enter the while loop, e.g in the case of 10, 8 - start is greater than stop.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a negative step,

- you have also `start > stop` so you do not enter the actual `while`
- as the step is negative, you want to do an addition, because if you substract a negative number, you go higher and never go from `start` to `stop` who is lower

Here how to handle both cases

```
def generate_list(start, stop, step):
    new_list = []
    if start <= stop and step >= 0:
        while start < stop:
            new_list.append(start)
            start += step
            
    elif start >= stop and step <= 0:
        while start > stop:
            new_list.append(start)
            start += step
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Wrong arguments {start} {stop} {step}") # this is optional
    
    return new_list
```

Calls like     `generate_list(2, 0, 1)` or `generate_list(10, 12, -2)` will raise an error

---

### Note

Using builtin method, your method is

```
def generate_list(start, stop, step):
    return list(range(start, stop, step))
```

Comment: oh thanks it works .. so you give an argument first "if statement" then the while loop so that if step is bigger than the stop it will enter the loop..

im new to programming good to know that i can initiate a if else statement outside a loop,..

Comment: @ZieGlear of couse `if` is totally independant of a `for` or  `while` loop